# Locate a dropdown element with selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, webautomation

[image: image for your reference]

I am trying to locate a dropdown element, but the dropdown is in a div class and there is no index select or id present for the dropdown values. I have already pasted the image below. Need some helping hands to resolve this problem.

Answer (score -1):

If you're trying to get the dropdown values, you need to expand the dropdown first. The values will populate thereafter